# Oracle DataAccess Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, oracle10g

We have one user (a developer) who is experiencing issues with Oracle DataAccess based on whether they are setup as a local administrator on their PC or not.

I dont know the inner workings of Oracle, so im really struggling to figure this one out.  My research seems to suggest the problem is around the oracle.dataaccess.dll and maybe linked to the fact that they have Visual Studio 2012 installed.

If the user is configured as a local administrator on thier PC, and they try to run an application they get the following error:

'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source: Oracle.DataAcess.GetData.GetUserPermissions.wsMS_load

If they are NOT an administrator, the application runs (but they have other problems related to not being as admin - they need admin permissions).

I have a feeling it is something to do with Oracle trying to look at the incorrect version of the .dll.  I have read some things about accessing the GAC and getting Oracle to reference a different version of the .dll, but as this stuff does not mean a lot to me I am getting out of my depth.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: this is a pretty generic error, and a common one in C#.  For example, if you had:  MyClass c;  ... c.myMethod();  you might see it.  You'll need to post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen problems with running as admin -vs- a restricted account in the past.

The problems I have seen are related to permissions of oracles install directory on the machine.   The quickest way to test for this problem is to `tnsping` your database using both users on the machine.

If one of them fails they most likely don't have rights to see libraries and config.

However, I have never seen this error message in association with this.

I would have the developer narrow down his code to a few lines that reproduce the problem and then edit the question with those lines.   It would greatly increase your chances of get a resolution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a VS 2012 and oracle.dataAccess.dll In a software my team developed. When looking dipper to the code and spending lots of hours configuring all kinds of stuff eventually turns out it was a compiling error due to a 64x/86x bit mismatch. Your exception is quite general but I hope this works for you too.